# Which one is better, setting OnClickListener on a Button or View?

Tags: android

I want to set `OnClickListener` on a `Button`. Should I cast it to the `Button` or let it in `View`? You can see from the code below, the former cast the `View` into `Button` while the later let the widget in a form of `View`. Is the later better because it doesn't need to do the casting or is it just do the same?

It's not that I don't understand how to set click listener on a button. I just want to know it in term of performance and best practice point of view.

```js
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

or

```js
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: SetOnclick is basically depends on your need. If you want this for View then use view. If you want button then use for button

Comment: If you look through the source code of [`Button`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/Button.java#Button) and [`View`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/view/View.java#View) you'll notice that `setOnClickListener` is defined in `View` only, thus there is no difference in computation. Cast itself suffers from an insignificant overhead of checking if cast is compatible (using [`checkcast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Same, You only save the cast (Performance).

if you dont need the View object I would prefer

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's no difference in performance. What changes is your code readability so, if you're setting a clickListener for a button and you also use the button instance later in the code you might want to use "button".setOnClickListener.

Since, most of the times you don't need to keep a reference of the clicked view, i'd suggest to use something like [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Comment: Not the OP but this is the first time I hear of something like ButterKnife. Thank you so much, this is going to make life a lot more efficient! Also, Jake Wharton is a hero.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise there is almost no difference. For readabillity I would suggest using Button and not View.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the difference in performance is minimal or simply there is no difference.

However, there is a difference between View and Button.

To shorten the answer and be as specific as possible ,I will tell you that if you want the button to be as "Standard" (Android standard at least) as possible, you should use the Button ,but if you want to sort of create a Custom Button, than you should go ahead and use the View.

To make it a bit more clear ,the Buttom is actually a View ,so when you use a Button, you actually use a View that is customized for the purpose of being a button and acting like one.

If you need more details, ask up,I will try to help or link you some documentation.